# Custom Controller - "Attempt to dereference Null object"

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a visual force page that calls a custom object controller extension, as below:

**Custom Controller**

```
public class ProjectApproval{

    ApexPages.StandardController controller;
        public ProjectApproval(ApexPages.StandardController con){
                controller = con;
        }

    ResearchProject__c project {get; set;}

    public PageReference save(){
         controller.save();
         String base = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
         Pagereference pr = New PageReference(base + '/ApprovalSuccess');
         pr.setRedirect(true);
         return pr;
    }

    public void declTick(){
        project.Head_of_School_Appr__c = false;
    }
}
```

**Visual Force Page**

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!ResearchProject__c.Head_of_School_Decline__c}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!declTick}" reRender="headAppr" />
</apex:inputCheckbox>
```

When I call the declTick() function, I get a Null reference error. I assume I am not instantiating the project object correctly, but I cannot work out how.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that exception because you are using `project` variable in `declTick` method which is not yet initialized i.e. it is still `null`. And when you try to perform operations on `null` object, you will get `Attempt to dereference a null object` exception.

As this is an `extension controller`, you can assign the `standard controller` `instance` to the `instance` that you are working with in `delTick` method so that it copies all the field values from standard instance to your instance. You can do that in `constructor` by using the [`standard controller's`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm) getRecord method.

```
public ProjectApproval(ApexPages.StandardController con){
    controller = con;
    project = (ResearchProject__c)con.getRecord();
}
```